# Flutter: App being crashed: yukams.app.background_locator_2.IsolateHolderService.getNotification

Tags: flutter, runtimeexception, illegalargumentexception, notificationmanager, flutter-workmanager

in flutter i have used workmanager and background_locator_2 and stored location co-ordinates in sharedpreference
workmanager calls function of background_locator_2 in every 15 mins
background_locator_2 stores the location co-ordinates in every 5 mins.
When app is terminated both workmanager and background_locator_2 are working fine. But after some days my app is being crashed.

My app is being crashed and sending reports as:

> yukams.app.background_locator_2.IsolateHolderService.getNotification
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
> Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:4804)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleServiceArgs
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2266)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8061)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:703)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:923)
> Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:3021)
> at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:3001)
> at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2984)
> at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2926)
> at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.createNotificationChannels (INotificationManager.java:3563)
> at android.app.NotificationManager.createNotificationChannels (NotificationManager.java:935)
> at android.app.NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel (NotificationManager.java:923)
> at yukams.app.background_locator_2.IsolateHolderService.getNotification (IsolateHolderService.java)
> at yukams.app.background_locator_2.IsolateHolderService.start (IsolateHolderService.java)
> at yukams.app.background_locator_2.IsolateHolderService.startHolderService (IsolateHolderService.java)
> at yukams.app.background_locator_2.IsolateHolderService.onStartCommand (IsolateHolderService.java)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:4786)

This error is mostly occuring in android version 11,12 and 13